# Dynamic auto input text width with css

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how easy this is, but because I usually code in php and output the html, I can do any calculations from there

**The problem:**

I have [a simple form](http://jsfiddle.net/7p66ope9/), and I want the input text fields to start right after the labels, but end at the same position. i.e. have a max of date of birth, and then expand everyone up to there

I tried some things with max-width/min-width and width but nothing seems to work

```
.input_field {
    max-width:150px;
    width:100%;
}
```

I would prefer a non javascript solution if possible!

Comment: have you considered how usable this will be with the labels and field alignment all messed up? all evidence points towards aligned fields and labels being best for the user when it comes to actually filling in a form

Comment: unfortunately, am just the programmer :)

Comment: @Alexandros why not wrap them into div with fixed width, and set the label into 'float:left' and the input to 'float:right'

Comment: @AlexNewbie try it, and you will see :)

Comment: @Alexandros - then your designers ought to learn a little about [form usability](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80167/alignment-of-input-fields-in-a-form-with-plain-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example using `FlexBox`: you could also set a `width` (or `min/max-width` to the `form` element (or to `ul` element)

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXdbab

**HTML**

```
<form>

  <ul>

    <li>
      <label>Label regular</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <label>Label2 really really longer</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </li>

    <li>
      <label>Label</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </li>

  </ul>

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  margin: 20px 0; padding: 0; 
  max-width: 500px;
}

form li {
   display: flex;
   margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

form input {
  margin-left: 2em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

---

Final note: Flexbox module is not supported on `IE<10.` but, on those browser only, you may use a script inside a conditional comment, e.g.

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
   <script>
      ...
   </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: how will this react to older browsers and ie?? i met flex somewhere else and found a problem with other browsers

Comment: older browser will show the form as in your example so the form is still usable. If you have specific requirements you should specify them in your question

Comment: pretty good actually, http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-box - all you lose though is a bit of styling in IE

Comment: well, its not a request but it would be better if :), ill give 10-15mins more and if there are no better answers then ill mark you as the one

Comment: ironically you might end up with a more usable form on older browsers :-P

Comment: or he can use a script inside conditional comments for older browser